# Return multiple values in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have these documents in my 'accounts' collection

```
{
        "name" : "Customer-1",
        "lines" : [
                {
                        "type" : "BroadBand",
                        "id" : "<MAC-ADDRESS-1>",
                        "status" : "ON"
                },
                {
                        "type" : "handset",
                        "id" : "<MSISDN-1>",
                        "status" : "ON"
                },
                {
                        "type" : "handset",
                        "id" : "34666468709",
                        "status" : "OFF"
                },
                {
                        "type" : "BroadBand",
                        "id" : "<MAC-ADDRESS-2>",
                        "status" : "OFF"
                }
        ]
}
```

I tried query :

```
db.accounts.find({$and: [ {"name":"Customer-1"}]},{"_id":0,"lines":{$elemMatch: {"type":"BroadBand"}}}).pretty()
```

but it gives me only first entry not all. So, I want my output to be only type as boradband with respective elements like below :

```
                        "type" : "BroadBand",
                        "id" : "<MAC-ADDRESS-1>",
                        "status" : "ON"

                        "type" : "BroadBand",
                        "id" : "<MAC-ADDRESS-2>",
                        "status" : "OFF"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use db.collection.aggregate() method to achieve this. Here is the query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
"$match": {
  "name": "Customer-1"
}},{
"$unwind": {
  "path": "$lines"
}},{
"$match": {
  "lines.type": "BroadBand"
}}, {
"$group": {
  "_id": "$name",
  "lines": {
    "$push": "$lines"
  }
}},{
"$project": {
  "name": "$_id",
  "lines": 1
}}])
```

Comment: great it's working..... Also if I want to check for all documents unlike the condition  name : Customer-1  ?

Comment: For that, you can remove the first "$match".

Comment: If it works for you, please approve the answer and mark it as useful.